# Any way to find out the sample rate, etc. of a .VOX file?

Tags: audio, conversion, file

I'm unfamiliar with .VOX files, and I've come across one that I'd like to try and unpack; however, I'm unsure the sample rate and other specifics needed to decode it. I've fiddled around with some .VOX file converters, but after trying nearly every option, I've still been unable to produce something that's recognizable as any kind of clear audio. Is there a way I can investigate the file and possibly find some clue as to how it's been encoded so I can decode it?

Answer (score 1):

From [this wikipedia article](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dialogic_ADPCM):

> Unlike a WAV file, a VOX file does not contain a header to specify the
>   encoding format or the sampling rate, so this information must be
>   known in order to play the file. If not known, it is normally assumed
>   that a VOX file is encoded with Dialogic ADPCM at a sampling rate of
>   8000 Hz. It is possible that a VOX file may be encoded in a format
>   other than Dialogic ADPCM, but this is not common